# Laptop cannot go to sleep correctly, after removing the hdmi cable from the TV

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, suspend, hdmi, gpu

I often hook up my laptop Acer Swift 3 to my TV screen to watch movies. When I remove the HDMI cable, closing the lid of my laptop (putting it to sleep), and then opening the lid again I always get greeted with this screen.

Error screen

[image: img_Error]

I have this dual boot for months but this problem started happening only some weeks ago

What can I do?
My video card is an UHD Graphics 620 Whisky Lake from Intel

Comment: But thats rather new. I have this dual boot for months, but this problem started to occur like 3 weeks ago

Comment: oh sorry edited the question!